# unable to find valid certification path to requested target (on windows with avast installed)

Tags: jakarta-mail

The following code is used to send email (using gmail) from a java application using javamail api.

It's working fine on Linux (Kubuntu 16.04) but not on Windows with Avast antivirus shields turned on.

```
    public void doSendGmail(){
    Connection con = Functions.ConnectToDB();
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sqlQuery = "select * from settings";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

        while(rs.next()){
            String email = rs.getString("Email");
            //String pass = rs.getString("Password");
            byte [] pass = rs.getBytes("Password");

            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CTR/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec,ivspec);
            byte [] plain_text = cipher.doFinal(pass);

            from = email;
            password = new String(plain_text);
        }

        con.close();// close the connection

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error retrieving email address and password\n"+e.toString(),
                "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    to = txtTo.getText();
    cc = txtCC.getText();
    bcc = txtBCC.getText();
    subject = txtSubject.getText();
    message_body = jtaMessage.getText();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");


    /*use authenticator as username and password are supplied 'on demand' i.e queried from database
    or supplied via a login dialog*/
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
        }
    });

    try {            
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
        if(!cc.equals("")){
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc));
        }
        if(!bcc.equals("")){
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(bcc));
        }
        message.setSubject(subject);

        if(filePathList.isEmpty()){// if a file(s) have not been attached...
            message.setText(message_body);
            Transport.send(message);
        }
        else{// if a file(s) have been attached
            MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            textPart.setText(message_body);// actual message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();// create multipart message
            multipart.addBodyPart(textPart);//add the text message to the multipart

            for(int i =0; i<filePathList.size(); i++){// use for loop to attach file(s)
                MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource((String)filePathList.get(i));
                attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                attachmentPart.setFileName((String)fileList.get(i));
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);// add the attachment to the multipart
                message.setContent(multipart);// add the multipart to the message
            }
            Transport.send(message);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message Sent!","Sent",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error sending email message\n"+e.toString(),
                "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

The following error message is displayed

[image]

When I disable all avast shields, it sends mail messages just perfectly.

How can the problem be fixed?

Do other antiviruses also have the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. I downloaded the InstallCert program from this link https://javaee.github.io/javamail/InstallCert.java. I then opened the file using a text editor (notepad++) and changed the port from 443 to 465 (SSL port for gmail) and saved the changes. After that I compiled the file and ran the program providing the gmail host i.e java InstallCert smtp.gmail.com. A file (jssecacerts) was generated. I copied this file in the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security folder. I was finally able to send email with all avast shields running!

Answer (score 0):

Avast is interposing on your secure communication with the server,
probably so it can prevent you from sending viruses or spam.  But since it's
acting as a "man in the middle", the exception is rightly telling you that
your connection is not secure.

The [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#installcert) tells you how to trust the Avast cert by using the
[InstallCert](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/InstallCert) program to add it to your trust store, or how to not check
the cert at all by setting the [`mail.smtp.ssl.trust`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.ssl.trust) property.

Comment: I did set the mail.smtp.ssl.trust property to true and false but it still didn't work i.e. props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust","true");

Comment: Did you read the property description (linked above)?  Setting it to "true" trusts the host named "true".  Try setting it to "*" to trust all hosts.

Comment: Yeah, i tried that as well. It didn't work. Let me try the InstallCert program and see if it works

Comment: I tried the install cert program but it didn't work as well. This is what I got after compiling and running the InstallCert program https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B90QkltJU5FaeXRhcWJYY2RyYW8

Comment: You're running InstallCert on the same machine that your app is running on, and that's also running Avast, right?  I don't know why Avast would prevent the java command running InstallCert from connecting, but would allow your app to connect while interposing on the connection.  Maybe you should check your Avast and/or firewall configuration?  Also, what version of JavaMail are you using?  If you set the **System** property `mail.socket.debug` to true, you'll get some debug output that might tell us why your app isn't working.

Comment: Well, I'm using javamail 1.5.5. I changed the port number from 443 to 465 in the InstallCert.java file and then compiled it. I then ran the java class and priovided the gmail host i.e java InstallCert smtp.gmail.com. Two certificates were installed as shown in these links but it still didn't work. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B90QkltJU5Fab2ctVktiX1NpUjA https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B90QkltJU5FaWllNeHF0ZmZkdTQ. Could it be because I ran the program on the Desktop? (I noticed a file with the name jssecacerts on the desktop after the operation)

Comment: The [instructions](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/InstallCert) tell you what to do with the jssecacerts file.

Comment: It worked after copying the jssecacerts file in my $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security directory. Thanks Bill